# MySQL query from 3 tables

Tags: mysql, sql

Suppose I have 3 tables like..

```
____________
|pid |pname|
| 1  |  a  |
| 2  |  b  |
| 3  |  c  |
------------
product

____________
|pid | qty |
| 1  |  5  |
| 2  |  8  |
| 1  |  5  |
------------
stock

____________
|pid | qty |
| 2  |  4  |
| 1  |  3  |
| 1  |  2  |
------------
sale
```

Now I want to display like at first select fast item (a) from product table then select total no of quantity. of the item from stock table and also from the sale table and subtract the value from total no of quantity of stock and total no of quantity of sale. Like this example --

```
________________________________
|pname |  Stock | Sale | remain |
|  A   |   10   |  5   |    5   |
|  B   |   8    |  4   |    4   |
|  C   |   0    |  0   |    0   |
---------------------------------
```

Comment: SELECT product.pid, pname, SUM(stock.qty) 
FROM product
LEFT OUTER JOIN stock ON product.pid = stock.pid
GROUP BY product.pid, pname
getting from stock table but want to substract from 2nd one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do the following:  See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/101c6/4)

```
select p.pname
  , st.TotalStock
  , sl.TotalSale
  , st.TotalStock - sl.TotalSale as Remain
from product p
inner join 
(
  select pid, sum(qty) as TotalStock
  from stock 
  group by pid
) st
  on p.pid = st.pid
inner join
(
  select pid, sum(qty) as TotalSale
  from sale
  group by pid
) sl
  on p.pid = sl.pid
```

The `INNER JOIN` will give you the records that exist in all tables, but if you want to see the records that exist in only some of the tables, then use a `LEFT JOIN` (see [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/101c6/22))

```
select p.pname
  , ifnull(st.TotalStock, 0) as TotalStock
  , ifnull(sl.TotalSale, 0) as TotalSale
  , ifnull(st.TotalStock, 0) - ifnull(sl.TotalSale, 0) as Remain
from product p
left join 
(
  select pid, sum(qty) as TotalStock
  from stock 
  group by pid
) st
  on p.pid = st.pid
left join
(
  select pid, sum(qty) as TotalSale
  from sale
  group by pid
) sl
  on p.pid = sl.pid
```